# Fetch the json from HttpEntity

Tags: json, scala, akka, httpentity

I have an object of akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity looking like HttpEntity("application/json", {Myjson here})

Is there a way i can fetch my json from the entity without any string manipulations(other than converting to a string and doing a split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a JSON parser and a glue code between the JSON parser and Akka Http called [Unmarshaller](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/common/unmarshalling.html).

Akka Http includes [unmarshallers for spray-json](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http-marshallers-scala/akka-http-spray-json/src/test/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/marshallers/sprayjson/SprayJsonSupportSpec.scala) library. You can find more unmarshallers in [hseeberger/akka-http-json](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json) library.

If you choose to use spray-json a pseudo code for that would be

```
case class MyJson(v1: String, v2: Int)

object JsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val myFormat = jsonFormat2(MyJson)
}

val resp: Future[MyJson] = Unmarshal(response).to[MyJson]
```